# JAX-RS REST: Route HTTP request based on MediaType parameter

Tags: rest, annotations, jax-rs, versioning, media-type

I have a fix MediaType + parameter and I was trying to route HTTP request based on the parameter.

```
@Path("/beer")

@GET
@Path("/all")
@Consumes("application/vnd.foo+json;type=boo/sth1")
@Produces("application/vnd.foo+json;type=koo/sth2")
Response getBeer();

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes("application/vnd.foo+json;type=woo/sth3")
@Produces("application/vnd.foo+json;type=hoo/sth4")
Response getBeer2();
```

I read lots of posts about versioning and how to use custom MediaType:

`+json` is a recognizable MediaType as `JSON`，so any accept header follow this format will be treated as `JSON`

when I sent a `GET` request
`http:/localhost:8000/beer/11` (should go to second `GET` method)

with

`--header 'Accept: application/vnd.foo+json;type="koo/sth2"'` (wrong type)

It gave me the correct response (in JSON format) with 200,
and `Content-Type` is `hoo/sth4`. Ideally it should return `406 not Acceptable`, but response type matches required `+json` format anyway, so it return as success.

Is there anyway i can made `type` value a must-match?
After search around I have couple of ideas but not sure if it would work:

1.Create a default mediaType + implement MessageBodyWriter/Reader (based on JacksonJsonProvider)

But in this way i need to implement MessageBodyWriter/Reader for every specific type value. def don't want to do that.

2.Create a new annotation, if the given type match this annotation, route request to this method, e.g.

```
    @Request("woo/sth3")
    @Response("hoo/sth4")
    Response getBeer2();
```

in ths case, should I rewrite a RequestDispatcher/ ResponseDispatcher or something?

Both solution looks ugly though, please share if you have good idea on this.

#### Udpate:

I edit my question to be more specifc, so type can be anything follow the format `"***/sth1"`, e.g. `"boo.foo/sth1"` and `"keepoo/sth2"`.